# Redirect is adding unwanted "id=XXXX" parameter to URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, shopify

I have a subdomain and a primary. The subdomain is a blog and is built on Wordpress, and the main site is on the Shopify platform. I set up some 301s from the blog to the primary domain and they work, but for some reason are adding an `id` parameter to the end of the urls.

I'm using the standard `Redirect 301 /old /new` in an htaccess file. I've never had this happen before when using this method, so I assume it's a Shopify thing. Has anyone ever experienced this, or know how to make it stop doing it?

Right now I have resolved the canonical issue using the follow Liquid code:

```
{% assign urlArray = canonical_url | split: '?' %}
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ urlArray | first }}">
```

I'd really like to remove it from the address bar as well if possible.